# Floating content in loading scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I'm trying to teach myself how to implement a loading scroll into my scroll, but I am having issues with the div being called. The content is not loading underneath the scroll, but instead pops up on the side and looks the part as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/713Marketing/9zXL5/52/) when scrolling down.

The code in question is

```
if(y >= contentHeight-30){

        movelist.innerHTML +='<div class ="newData"><center>hey look at me</center></div>';
                }
```

I want to append content to the bottom of the scroll before the bottom is reached. Any insight or tips would be extremely helpful and appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many errors in the code.

To answer your question: 
You need to add `float:left;` to your div.NewData. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zXL5/61/)

Second: To add comments in CSS you need to use `/* */` and not `<!-- -->`.
Commenting with `<!-- -->` is not recognized by CSS so all that's underneath will not be applied.

Third: Ids are unique. All your `<li>` have the same id. Use a class instead.

Comment: Thank you for not only helping me fix it, but explaining it so that I can learn!!! I appreciate that alot @ComputerArts

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear: left;` and `float: left;` to the class on the div you are adding it, then add additional stylings to make it fit the width.